# Why process does not (seem to) exist before fifo read

Tags: shell, process, io-redirection, fifo

I have a trivial Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

sys.stderr.write('I am %s' % os.getpid())
sys.stderr.flush()

print "hello"

sys.stderr.write('I am done')
```

When I run this script from Bash and redirect the stdout to FIFO:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ /pyscript > fifo
```

the strange thing is, that before I read from the FIFO:

- I won't get the "I am (PID)" message,
- I can't see the script using `ps -ef`
- and using *lsof*, I can't see anybody has the *fifo* file open!

Once I do read from the FIFO, the both messages that I'm writing to stderr appear at once.

What is happening?

---

The background: I'm writing a test where I create FIFO and write 'hello' to it; then I run a test and expect the SUT to *not* read from it; ie. just ignore the file.  I tried to do `mkfifo test_fifo; /bin/echo hello > test_fifo &; run_the_test; killall echo` but to my surprise, the `echo` process never exists!  How should I "clean up" after such test (apart from `rm test_fifo`)...?

Answer (score 6):

The shell will not run a program until any file redirections have been completed successfully. The command `pyscript > fifo` will cause the shell to fork and then try to open `fifo`. This will succeed only when some process has opened `fifo` for reading. Until then, the child shell will be in pipe wait.

```
$ (sleep 10;ps -l -t pts/0)&
[1] 2574
$ pyscript > fifo
F S   UID    PID   PPID WCHAN  TTY    CMD
0 S  1000   2554   2535 wait   pts/0  bash  //interactive shell
1 S  1000   2574   2554 wait   pts/0  bash  //fork of shell, parent of sleep and ps
1 S  1000   2576   2554 pipe_w pts/0  bash  //fork of shell, waiting to open fifo
0 R  1000   2577   2574 -      pts/0  ps
```

Answer (score 4):

> A pipe or FIFO has to be open at both ends simultaneously. If you read from a pipe or FIFO file that doesn’t have any processes writing to it (perhaps because they have all closed the file, or exited), the read returns end-of-file. Writing to a pipe or FIFO that doesn’t have a reading process is treated as an error condition; it generates a SIGPIPE signal, and fails with error code EPIPE if the signal is handled or blocked.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html

Comment: Nice, I did not know that FIFO must be open simultaneously; so certainly there must be some magic that the shell does to make it work in the first place...?

Comment: Not really magic; the order of events is 1) The shell makes a system call to open the target file for writing. 2) The shell blocks until that system call returns. 3) The shell runs the command. With a regular file, there is no discernible gap between 1 and 2; it happens almost immediately. With a FIFO, the system call doesn't return until another process opens the FIFO for reading, which can delay 2 indefinitely.